# How to do automatic log-in in webpage?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to automatically log in to bing.com using htmlelement but my code its not working, however its working for other sites like hotmail and facebook.
Here is my code:

```
     void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
           {

               HtmlElementCollection elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
               foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
               {
                   if (element.Name == "login")
                   {
                       element.SetAttribute("value", email);
                   }
                   if (element.Name == "passwd")
                   {
                       element.SetAttribute("value", pass);
                   }
                   if (element.Name == "SI")
                   {
                       element.InvokeMember("click");

                   }
```

what I'm doing wrong?